# Linking libsox in Windows

Tags: linker, sox

can anyone help me with linking libsox to my program in Windows? I have made a static library libsox.lib according to directions in INSTALL file in sox 14.2.0 source code version. Is there any way to build a dynamic library? I think it should be easier way...

Comment: Try to give more details, like which compiler you use to compile with (gcc under cygwin?). Error messages?

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using?
How are you currently building and linking the library?

[This link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/XDllPt1.aspx) gives some info on linking libraries in VC++ under windows, but without more info from you no-one will be able to help